# How to get a file URL uploaded in Google chat

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chat

I've created a google chat bot and i want to add the functionality of letting the user upload files while conversing with the bot and put the files somewhere else.

Now i want to know the URL or link of where the file is stored, but I'm not sure how to get it.

I see that whenever i try uploading a file into the chat, the request body does not contain the file or a link to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible; the chat bot can't see files sent over Google Chat and so obtaining this and doing something with it isn't possible from the Hangouts side of things. You'd need to get users to upload files to a Drive folder or something akin to this to work with it.

Comment: Agreed with @RafaGuillermo, ask users to upload file on GDrive/Shared Drive and ask for links directly.